# Creating a new array with dictionaries from existing array (extract specific key value paths)

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary

Currently working on a way to create a new `NSMutableDictionary` from my returned JSON data. I want to extract: `tide.tideSummary.data.type` and `tide.tideSummary.date.epoch` - I want to create a new array of dictionaries but with these 2 keys.

**Below is what I have now:**

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in self.tideSummary) {

NSString *type = [self.tideSummary valueForKeyPath:@"data.type"];
NSString *date = [self.tideSummary valueForKeyPath:@"date.epoch"];

[sunCycleDictionary setValue:(type) forKey:@"type"];
[sunCycleDictionary setValue:(date) forKey:@"epoch"];
}
```

Right now my `NSLog` returns perfectly for each key. Sample log as of now, **what is incorrect**

```
 epoch =     (
    1388724761,
    1388746063,
    ...
```

**My goal it to make this output:** - an array of dictionaries.

```
 {
 type: Sunrise,
 epoch: 1336116677
 },
 {
 type: Sunset,
 epoch: 1336116677
 },
 {
 type: Moonset,
 epoch: 1336116677
 },
 ...
```

I think I am pretty close, I just need to join those 2 key value pairs in their own object. Do *I need to create a `NSMutableArray` and `addObject` to the previously created dictionary?*

**Data I am working with:**

```
"tideSummary": [
            {
                "date": {
                    "pretty": "11:58 AM PST on December 19, 2013",
                     ...
                    "epoch": "1387483136"
                },
                "utcdate": {
                    "pretty": "7:58 PM GMT on December 19, 2013",
                    ...
                    "epoch": "1387483136"
                },
                "data": {
                    "height": "5.97 ft",
                    "type": "High Tide"
                }
            },
```

Thoughts on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to your output but the shown output is not fully Dictionary it is an array of Dictionaries, so you need to do something like this.

```
    NSMutableArray *finalOutput = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //Add this

    for (NSDictionary *dict in self.tideSummary)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *sunCycleDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; //Add this

        NSString *type = [self.tideSummary valueForKeyPath:@"data.type"];
        NSString *date = [self.tideSummary valueForKeyPath:@"date.epoch"];

        [sunCycleDictionary setValue:(type) forKey:@"type"];
        [sunCycleDictionary setValue:(date) forKey:@"epoch"];

        [finalOutput addObject: sunCycleDictionary]; //Add this

    }

    NSLog(@"out of loop: %@", finalOutput);
```

Comment: @KumarKl I would want to be doing something like ```addObject: sunCycleDictionary```

Comment: @Coughlin :YEs, but Here actually adding the same array object

Comment: That exports something like this: http://pastie.org/8595473 - each key needs to be in its own dictionary then that is added so each index has  2 keys ```type``` ```epoch```

Comment: @KumarKl it was by mistake. Need to add dictionary to array.

Comment: See my updated question with some formatting. I think you may have looked at the NSLog output from what I had.

Comment: @βhargavḯ Yup, see above for my logged link. It still exports them all out in a single dictionary

Comment: @Coughlin look for //Add this in above code. You need to initialize your dictionary inside the loop.

Comment: @βhargavḯ Ah ok! So with us initializing the dictionary inside the loop we are saying each time this runs, create a new dictionary?

Comment: @Coughlin yes you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSMutableArray *outputArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *dict in self.tideSummary)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *sunCycleDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSString *type = [dict valueForKeyPath:@"data.type"];
    NSString *date = [dict valueForKeyPath:@"date.epoch"];

    [sunCycleDictionary setValue:(type) forKey:@"type"];
    [sunCycleDictionary setValue:(date) forKey:@"epoch"];

    [outputArray addObject:sunCycleDictionary];

}

NSLog(@"output array : %@", outputArray);
```

Comment: Yeah, this does the trick. So ideally I was missing the last line where you have ```addObject```

Comment: I think you were missed `[dict valueForKeyPath:@"data.type"]` this.?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This

NSMutableArray *temp =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSDictionary *dict in self.tideSummary) {

NSString *type = [self.tideSummary valueForKeyPath:@"data.type"];
NSString *date = [self.tideSummary valueForKeyPath:@"date.epoch"];
NSLog(@"type: %@", type);

[sunCycleDictionary setValue:(type) forKey:@"type"];
[sunCycleDictionary setValue:(date) forKey:@"epoch"];
[temp addObject: sunCycleDictionary];
NSLog(@"in loop: %@", temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            int i=0;
            while (i<[_arayResjoBID count]) {

                NSLog(@"%d",i);
                NSDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

                [dict setValue:[[_arayResjoBID objectAtIndex:i]valueForKeyPath:@"BarCode"] forKey:@"barcode"];
                [dict setValue:[[_arayResjoBID objectAtIndex:i] valueForKeyPath:@"ItemName"] forKey:@"itemname"];
                [dict setValue:[[_arayResjoBID objectAtIndex:i] valueForKeyPath:@"Quantity"] forKey:@"quantity"];
                [dict setValue:@"NO"  forKey:@"Yes"];

                [_arayFilter insertObject:dict atIndex:i];

                i++;
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"%@",_arayFilter);
        [self.tableView reloadData];
```

OUTPUT: in debug area
(
        {
        Yes = NO;
        barcode = 1002690094467;
        itemname = "Box  Oversized 100X80x80";
        quantity = 5;
    },
        {
        Yes = NO;
        barcode = 1002690094474;
        itemname = "Road Case Large";
        quantity = 2;
    },
        {
        Yes = NO;
        barcode = 1002690094481;
        itemname = "Road Case New Double";
        quantity = 4;
    }
)